# User Authentication in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

Securing a CodeIgniter Site
I am trying to use the authentication method suggested on the Tuts+ site at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-authentication-with-codeigniter--net-20248.

After validating the user I create a session variable as follows:

```
    $_SESSION['username'] = $this->input->post('email_address');
```

Tuts+ then suggests the following be placed in all controllers:

```
    public function __construct() {
           session_start();
        parent::__construct();
        if(!ISSET($_SESSION['username'])){
           redirect('admin_controller');
        }
    }
```

This works without any problems when I place it in my main_controller, but when I add the code to other controllers I get:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - > > headers already sent (output started at /………….../application/controllers> /contact_controller.php:146)

This is probably a really dumb question but how do I check for the session variable in the other controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about session it's about `redirect` function; it must be called without any output before it, please check the file `/contact_controller.php` at line 146 if it's echoing anything before redirect.

Further information about [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment. There is no line 146 in /contact_controller.php. Code ends at line 144.

Comment: There should be something ;) if there is any character or even empty space, new line after closing php tag `?>` will cause that issue.

Comment: Yes, that was it - a few newlines after the closing ?> tag. Thanks for taking the time to look into this for me :-)